# Lower Time Frame

Tags: pine-script

I work on 15min timeframe. I want sma on 1min timeframe.

```
one_minclose = security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", low, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
oneminma = sma(one_minclose,20)
plot(oneminma, title="1minma", color=#000000)
```

But I don't think the moving is plotting the sma of 1min value.  So, can we not request data of lesser timeframe than the timeframe on the chart.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks
Sudharshan

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `resolution` argument in security as follows:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script",resolution="1")
length = input(14),src = input(close)
//----
plot(sma(src,length))
```